# TestNG + MockServer Running two test suite sequentially

Tags: testng, mockserver

I have two test suite. Project is gradle project which has two module. Each of them has their own unit tests. I used mock server (https://www.mock-server.com/) to mock server endpoints. If I run each suite separately they works. But when I do a project build from the root of the directory like (./gradlew clean build) unit tests failed because of port binding issue.

I set parallel=false in suite.xml for both of them. But its not working. Seems they are running parallel and fighting for the port.

How can I run these two suite sequentially.